# What is causing this Graphics2D rendering stutter/lag

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, game-development, game-loop

**Mouse.java**

```
package game.input;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;

// holds information about mouse events.
// eg, presses of buttons.
public class Mouse extends MouseAdapter {
    // the position of the mouse.
    public static int x, y;
    
    // Is the mouse pressed.
    public static boolean pressed;
    
    // Is the mouse held.
    public static boolean held;
    
    // Is the mouse hovered over the window.
    public static boolean focused;
    
    // Is the mouse being dragged.
    public static boolean dragging;
    
    // no mouse wheel support.
    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent event) {}
    
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        dragging = true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        focused = true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
        focused = false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        held = true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        held = false;
        dragging = false;
        pressed = true;
    }
}
```

**Keyboard.java**

```
package game.input;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

// holds information about key events.
public class Keyboard extends KeyAdapter {
    // which keys are being held down.
    private static boolean[] heldKeys;
    
    // which keys are being clicked
    private static boolean[] clickedKeys;
    
    // size of arrays.
    private final int size;
    
    public Keyboard() {
        // there are 255 valid key codes.
        // plus one for the array size.
        size = 256;
        
        clickedKeys = new boolean[size];
        heldKeys = new boolean[size];
    }
    
    // when the key is pressed.
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        // catches out of bounds error.
        if(event.getKeyCode() > size)
            return;
        
        // key is being held.
        heldKeys[event.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        // catches out of bounds error.
        if(event.getKeyCode() > size)
            return;
        
        // key is let go.
        heldKeys[event.getKeyCode()] = false;
        
        // when key is let go, it gets interpreted as it being pressed.
        clickedKeys[event.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }
    
    // returns whether or not the key is held.
    public static boolean keyHeld(Key key) {
        if(heldKeys != null)
            return heldKeys[key.keyCode];
        return false;
    }
    
    // returns whether or not the key is clicked.
    public static boolean keyClicked(Key key) {
        if(clickedKeys != null)
            return clickedKeys[key.keyCode];
        return false;
    }
    
    // resets key input.
    public static void resetKeys() {
        if(clickedKeys != null)
            for(int i = 0; i < clickedKeys.length; i++)
                clickedKeys[i] = false;
    }
    
    public enum Key {
        // movement keys.
        LEFT(37), UP(38), RIGHT(39), DOWN(40),
        
        // x key.
        A(88),
        
        // z key.
        B(90),
        
        // enter key.
        START(10);
        
        private int keyCode;
        
        private Key(int keyCode) {
            this.keyCode = keyCode;
        }
    };
}
```

**Game.java**

```
package game;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import game.input.Keyboard;
import game.input.Mouse;
import game.room.Room;
import userInterface.containers.BB_Window;

// creates a new game
public final class Game {
    // the window that the game resides in.
    private static BB_Window window;
    
    // the current room that is drawn to the window.
    private static Room room;
    
    private static GameLoop gameLoop;
    
    // game constructor cannot be called.
    private Game() {}
    
    // inits the game.
    // ie, adds input to the game (key and mouse).
    public static void init(BB_Window window) {
        if(gameLoop != null)
            return;
        
        // creates mouse and keyboard listeners.
        Mouse mouse = new Mouse();
        Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();
        
        // adds input listeners to the window.
        window.getJFrame().addKeyListener(keyboard);
        window.getCanvas().addMouseListener(mouse);
        window.getCanvas().addMouseMotionListener(mouse);
        
        // init game loop
        gameLoop = new GameLoop();
        
        // init window
        Game.window = window;
        
        gameLoop.start();
    }
    
    // updates the current room and resets input.
    protected static void update() {
        // if room doesn't exist, don't update it.
        if(room == null)
            return;
        
        // updates current room.
        Game.room.update();
        
        // resets mouse input.
        Mouse.pressed = false;
        
        // resets key input.
        Keyboard.resetKeys();
        
        // if a mouse or key button is clicked,
        // then it would have to be reset to false here.
    }
    
    // renders the current room.
    protected static void render() {
        // if room doesn't exist, don't render it.
        if(room == null)
            return;
        
        // creates graphics object from the window canvas.
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) window.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy().getDrawGraphics();
        
        // creates the screen for next drawing.
        graphics.clearRect(0, 0, window.getWidth(), window.getHeight());
        
        // renders the current room.
        Game.room.render(graphics);
        
        // shows the buffer.
        window.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy().show();
        
        // removes graphics object.
        graphics.dispose();
    }
    
    // sets the current room to a new one.
    public static void setRoom(Room newRoom) {
        newRoom.init();
        Game.room = newRoom;
    }
    
    // returns the current room.
    public static Room getRoom() {
        return Game.room;
    }
    
    // returns width of window.
    public static int getWindowWidth() {
        return window.getWidth();
    }
    
    // returns height of window.
    public static int getWindowHeight() {
        return window.getHeight();
    }
    
    // stops the game loop.
    public static void stop() {
        gameLoop.stop();
    }
}
```

**GameLoop.java**

```
package game;

public class GameLoop implements Runnable {
    // the thread that the game runs on.
    private Thread thread;
    
    // is the game running.
    private boolean running;
    
    // starts the game loop.
    // inits the thread and calls its start method.
    public void start() {
        // you can't start the game if it is started.
        if(running)
            return;
        
        // starts the game.
        running = true;
        
        // creates thread.
        thread = new Thread(this);
        
        // starts the game.
        // ie, calls thread.run();
        thread.start();
    }
    
    // stops the game loop.
    // interrupts the thread and terminates the currently running JVM.
    public void stop() {
        // you can't end the game if it is ended.
        if(!running)
            return;
        
        // ends the game.
        running = false;
        
        // interrupts the thread.
        // ie, ends the thread.
        // this will always end the thread,
        // because running is set to false.
        thread.interrupt();
        
        // ends the program.
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    // this is the game loop.
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // holds information about each frames elapsed time.
        double start, previous = System.nanoTime() / 1_000_000_000.0;
        
        // time.
        double actualFrameTime, realTime = 0;
        
        // should the game be rendered.
        boolean render;
        
        // fps
        final int FPS = 60;
        final double DESIRED_FRAME_TIME = 1.0 / FPS;
        
        // while the game is running
        while(running) {
            // calculates the elapsed time of the frame.
            // converts from nano seconds to seconds
            // by dividing by one billion.
            start = System.nanoTime() / 1_000_000_000.0;
            actualFrameTime = start - previous;
            previous = start;
            
            // the game time is updated by the elapsed frame time.
            realTime += actualFrameTime;
            
            // resets it to back to false.
            render = false;
            
            // if time surpasses desired frame time, game should update.
            while(realTime >= DESIRED_FRAME_TIME && realTime != 0) {
                realTime -= DESIRED_FRAME_TIME;
                Game.update();
                
                // if the game is updated, the game should render.
                // if the game is not updated, the game doesn't render.
                render = true;
            }
            
            if(render)
                Game.render();
            // sleep if game should not render.
            // reduces cpu usage by a lot.
            else
                try {
                    // sleep for one millisecond.
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**BB_Window.java**

```
package userInterface.containers;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

// the JFrame that the game will reside in.
public final class BB_Window {
    private JFrame window;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Dimension windowDimension;
    
    // constructs the canvas, window, and buffer.
    public BB_Window(String title, int width, int height) {
        // creates dimension.
        windowDimension = new Dimension(width, height);
        
        // creates a canvas with a bunch of defaults.
        canvas = new Canvas();
        
        // sets a non-changeable size.
        canvas.setPreferredSize(windowDimension);
        canvas.setMinimumSize(windowDimension);
        canvas.setMaximumSize(windowDimension);
        
        // cannot be focused for event listeners.
        canvas.setFocusable(false);
        
        // creates window with a bunch of defaults.
        window = new JFrame();
        window.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
        
        // center of screen.
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        
        if(bufferStrategy == null)
            canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
    }
    
    // returns the frame.
    public JFrame getJFrame() {
        return window;
    }
    
    // returns the window width.
    public int getWidth() {
        return windowDimension.width;
    }
    
    // returns the window height.
    public int getHeight() {
        return windowDimension.height;
    }
    
    // returns the canvas.
    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }
}
```

**Room.java**

```
package game.room;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

// future functionality might be added,
// which is why this class is abstract and not interface.

// represents a room/location in your Game
// eg, a town, a house, a forest, and a cave are all examples of rooms.
public abstract class Room {
    public abstract void init();
    public abstract void update();
    public abstract void render(Graphics2D graphics);
}
```

I feel that these files are the only ones needed to understand how my game library functions.

However, I notice that whenever I test out my game library, there is a very noticeable stutter that occurs every few seconds, and lasts for a few seconds. This is very annoying. However, what is more annoying is that this blocky/laggy movement is more noticeable on my computer than on other computers. What is going on with my computer for this to be occurring? How do I fix this? Here is an example of how my game library works.

```
Game.setRoom(new Room() {
    private int x, y;
    
    @Override
    public void init() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void update() {
        x++;
        y++;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void render(Graphics2D graphics) {
        graphics.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
    }});

Game.init(new BB_Window("Test", 640, 640));
```

This example program draws a rectangle that moves diagonally down the screen.
However, sometimes, the rectangle seems to "skip" pixels and moves more than it should.
I tried recording my screen to show exactly what is going on, but for some reason the stutter is not showing up in the video.

I tried enabling hardware acceleration by doing

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
```

but that didn't do anything.

My computer isn't bad at all, so why is the game running more smoother on other computers than on mine?

And what can I do to fix this in my game library?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are using 3rd party classes so we can't test. *I notice that whenever I test out my game library, there is a very noticeable stutter that occurs every few seconds, and lasts for a few seconds.* - I don't notice any problems in this working example: I notice that whenever I test out my game library, there is a very noticeable stutter that occurs every few seconds, and lasts for a few seconds.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll add it in.

Comment: Now you should be able to test it on your machine

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1);` ← That’s why.  You’re hogging your CPU.  Yes, sleep(1) is better than no sleep at all, but you’re still running your game loop absurdly frequently.  The frame rate for drawing isn’t the only frame rate that matters;  how often do you really need to repeat the game loop?  Is there any benefit to advancing the game’s state more often than, say, 20 times per second?  Is any human going to notice if your game takes 0.05 seconds to respond to input?

Comment: 1) I gave you an example in a single file you can download and test. I'm not about to copy 6 classes. If you want us to help make it easy. 2) The point of my link was for you to look at the code to understand how it worked an then make changes.  3) Don't use magic numbers. The values for all your enums are magic numbers. Use the fields provided by the API, for example, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT. 4) You should be using `Key Bindings`, not a KeyListener to handle keyboard events. 5) Use a `Swing Timer`, not Thread.sleep() to schedule animation.